# Issue with #[pallet::generate_storage_info]

Tags: storage, boundedvec

I was digging into substrate's  **storage_info** macro
 https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/macros/#palletgenerate_storage_info.

To get hands dirty checked code from 
https://github.com/yourarj/substrate-node-template/blob/3d4e7f18e0e1141975e7bb74a6ea64c9eef0dabe/pallets/kittens/src/lib.rs#L13 
which is fork of official substrate-node-template

But not able to compile with the specified macro

my code looks something like

[image]

```
   Compiling pallet-kittens v4.0.0-dev (/home/awesome/workspaces/subsstrate/yourarj/substrate-node-template/pallets/kittens)
error: expected one of: `generate_store`, `without_storage_info`, `storage_version`
  --> pallets/kittens/src/lib.rs:14:12
   |
14 |     #[pallet::generate_storage_info]
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`generate_storage_info` is now the default. So, you don't need to specify it anymore. For your error here it means, just remove this attribute.

For reference, it means that if you are just developing a pallet and don't need the `storage_info` for now. You can use `without_storage_info` and then it will not be required.

Comment: Shouldn't the documentation be updated to reflect that?

Comment: There is already an open pr.