# Storing BTreeMap and Vec gives error

Tags: frame

New substrate version requires derive MaxEncodedLen

I have a following storage:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Default, Clone, Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub struct SortitionSumTree<AccountId> {
    pub k: u64,
    pub stack: Vec<u64>,
    pub nodes: Vec<u64>,
    pub ids_to_node_indexes: BTreeMap<AccountId, u64>, // citizen id, node index
    pub node_indexes_to_ids: BTreeMap<u64, AccountId>, // node index, citizen id
}
```

But it gives error:

```
no function or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<u64>` in the current scope

no function or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for struct `std::collections::BTreeMap` in the current scope
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that `BTreeMap` by default isn't bounded. Meaning you could store an unlimited amount of data in these maps. For this case there exists the `BoundedBTreeMap` type in Substrate. There you statically need to define the upper number of data that will be stored inside the `BTreeMap`.

You can also disable the requirement for `MaxEncodedLength` by setting the [`without_storage_info`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1323/73) attribute. If your pallet should not be used in Parachain, that is completely fine, because there you don't have the requirement to produce a storage proof which needs to be predictable.